# Microsoft Dynamic CRM 2016 vs custom CRM Training Management

Tags: .net, dynamic, customization, crm

We are a training organisation dealing with a lot of data to report and a lot of student. We run our training delivery through Moodle and its fine. Customised as per our requirements etc.
Management is thinking of implementing MS Dynamic CRM as a all connected solution which we will be able to extend as per our requirement. the list of requirements are huge. Consider the basic CRM functionalities would be barely used in the long run and we will need solutions and features built just for us. This is not only adding new fields or forms. But even theri validation. Adding features like process workflow, contact matching, on demand sync etc.

Now given all these complexities involved Is it still a good idea to walk the MS Dynamic path or should we rather think of building something from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

That's a typical use case of Dynamics CRM. Whilst CRM is packaged with Sales, Service, and Marketing, it can be customised for a wide and varied range of applications.

Comment: And almost always seldom used the way it is supposed to. No wonder they promote it more as XRM (extendable).